# dust template iterate a list of map

Tags: java, dust.js

just wondering how to iterate a list of map reading from config file, for example, saving as a list of map `List<Map<String, String>>`

```
<list>
    <map>
        <entry key="myKey" value="abc"/>
        <entry key="myValue" value="123"/>
    </map>
    <map>
        <entry key="myKey" value="def"/>
        <entry key="myValue" value="456"/>
    </map>
</list>
```

so in rendered json it looks like

```
myList: [
    {myKey: "abc", myValue:123"}
    {myKey: "def", myValue:456"}
]
```

So far I tried but not working

```
{#myList}
  <div class="{myKey}">{myValue}</div>
{/myList}
```

in hoping to get

```
<div class="abc">123</div>
<div class="def">456</div>
```

I know I could potentially create a class for example myObject.java to return a list of myObject to render like in tutorial, just wondering if there is any way we can get around it? Thanks

Comment: A Dust context is a JSON object. You'll have to parse your XML into JSON at some point.

Answer (score -1):

I think that [Free marker template](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html) is closest to your demand

Comment: Any one who vote down this comment, please tell the reason why to help me improve what wrong!

Comment: They are asking how to do this in Dust, not in freemarker.

Comment: Thanks @Interrobang